# Oracle Date Value is changed during String aggregate Functions

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c, listagg

When I run the below 2 statements, the output I got is

```
SELECT TO_DATE ('01/01/99', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS date_a FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE ('01/01/99', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS date_a FROM DUAL
Output
---------
1/1/0099
1/1/0099
```

Now - if I try to concatenate the above 2 values without altering the value using a listagg function, the output is changed like this.

```
SELECT listagg(date_a,'#') WITHIN GROUP(order by date_a)  FROM 
(
SELECT TO_DATE ('01/01/99', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS date_a FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE ('01/01/99', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS date_a FROM DUAL
)
Output
--------
01-JAN-99#01-JAN-99
```

I need the output as `1/1/00999#1/1/00999`

Please help me to resolve this problem

Comment: Use `TO_CHAR()`, not `TO_DATE()`.

Comment: I provided the above query as a sample. In my actual scenario date_a is a DB column with datatype as Date.

Comment: Why do you perform `TO_DATE()` on a value which is already a DATE?

Comment: I know it's only an example, but why are you using a two-digit year value (99) with a four-character mask (YYYY)? Or at all, or that matter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT LISTAGG (TO_CHAR (date_a, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), '#') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY date_a)
  FROM (SELECT TO_DATE ('01/01/99', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS date_a FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT TO_DATE ('01/01/99', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS date_a FROM DUAL)
```

Answer (score 3):

You have implicit conversions!

Listagg accepts character input. So the database has an implicit to_char around your date values. You can see this by changing the nls_date_format parameter:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd-mon-yyyy';

select listagg(date_a,'#') within group(order by date_a)  dts
from 
(
select to_date ('01/01/99', 'mm/dd/yyyy') as date_a from dual
union all
select to_date ('01/01/99', 'mm/dd/yyyy') as date_a from dual
);

DTS                       
01-jan-0099#01-jan-0099  

alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd';

select listagg(date_a,'#') within group(order by date_a) dts
from 
(
select to_date ('01/01/99', 'mm/dd/yyyy') as date_a from dual
union all
select to_date ('01/01/99', 'mm/dd/yyyy') as date_a from dual
);

DTS                     
0099-01-01#0099-01-01
```

Avoid this by explicitly to_charing your dates:

```
select listagg( to_char ( date_a, 'mm/dd/yyyy' ),'#') within group(order by date_a) dts 
from 
(
select to_date ('01/01/99', 'mm/dd/yyyy') as date_a from dual
union all
select to_date ('01/01/99', 'mm/dd/yyyy') as date_a from dual
);

DTS                     
01/01/0099#01/01/0099
```

Answer (score 1):

In yours just use `to_char()` that said in comment

```
SELECT listagg(date_a,'#') WITHIN GROUP(order by date_a)  FROM 
    (
    SELECT to_char( TO_date ('01/01/0099', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),'MM/DD/YYYY') AS date_a FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT to_char(TO_date ('01/01/0099', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),'MM/DD/YYYY') AS date_a FROM DUAL
    )
```